# How are all of these title/position fields correlated?

Tags: support, profile-page, developer-story

There are four fields that confuse me greatly and I don't think I have a correct understanding of how they are supposed to correlate. Could someone please explain with a clear example that will highlight the difference between them and which should be the same?

1. **Edit Profile and Settings - Public information - Title**;
2. **Edit Profile and Settings - Career - Current position**;
3. **Developer Story - Title**; which actually ask for a position in placeholder:

   > What's your current position?
4. **Developer Story - Experience - Current Position** (the timeline with past experience/employment history)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one is a free-form subtitle for your profile, shown [on your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) below your display name. It doesn't have to be your current position, it can be anything you want (within the limits of the Code of Conduct of course, keep in professional).

The second set of fields (current position combined with the value of the *at* field) are only used if you *did not set a title*. Put differently: filling in a position and a company in the *Career* section creates a default *title* field value, used when you don't use the free-form title field in #1. If you do set a free-form title, the values you fill in here are not used anywhere else.

Your Developer Story title is used in your Developer Story only. Your Developer Story is not necessarily public, and used in a different setting from your Stack Overflow profile page, which always is public. Your Developer Story is your CV, sent to potential employers when you use the Stack Overflow careers features. It appears at the top of your Developer Story (both in the story view and the traditional view). Treat this like you would the header of a traditional CV. While you could put a funny joke in your profile title, presumably you would want to put your actual position in this field.

Number 4 is just your employment history. This is the place where you tell about your current position, just like you would describe past positions.

Comment: Does it mean, that ideally (for the perfect consistency) they all are supposed to be the same? 2 and 4 are about the same thing, 1, _by default_, is filled with 2 and 3 is optionally synced with 1.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind: nope. You can pick different things for the different fields. 2 is ignored if 1 has a value. How you want to be perceived by potential employers influences 3 and 4.