# Broken user profiles, only on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Today I found [three](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4370109/) [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3007075/) [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6216160/) pages on Stack Overflow which throw an error, however, their [respective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4370109/) [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3007075/) counterparts still work, as do the rest of their [network](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/26708/) [profiles](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/534516/).

Comments from [our resident](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384240/broken-user-profiles-only-on-stack-overflow#comment691238_384240) [ninja puppy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384240/broken-user-profiles-only-on-stack-overflow#comment691242_384240) suggest that with moderator status it is still possible to view those profiles.

Further comments by [another ninja](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384240/broken-user-profiles-only-on-stack-overflow#comment691259_384240) [suggest that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384240/broken-user-profiles-only-on-stack-overflow#comment691265_384240) indeed the profile page is broken, as well as the Developer Story, as the activity tab and others still function.

Why are these profiles broken and can they be fixed?

Comment: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7686137#7686137

Comment: I also see broken profile pics and can't visit my profile page. Redirects me to https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/761095/bahrep

Comment: There was maintenance on meta earlier, didn't check if it was also true for SO main but maybe related?

Comment: Here's another one: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5752218/ubuntugod (and respective [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5752218/ubuntugod) works as well)

Comment: I think those are plenty of data points, enough to make the point :P

Comment: Seems they're working okay now?

Comment: @ivarni meta didn't break; SO main did.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Oh, I just started on a script to test all userprofiles ....

Comment: @JonClements the first three links? Don't for me, still broken.

Comment: @Adriaan those 3 in your Q work fine... so does the one Patrick posted above... I can see bahrep's profile page just fine as well...

Comment: Now we only need to workout what is different between @JonClements and us ...

Comment: @JonClements perhaps your mod status affects the outcome? Try opening in an incognito window or a browser you're not logged into.

Comment: Maybe that strange symbol next the name is clue.

Comment: Ahh... okay yeah... incognito I get an "oops" page... Don't see how a diamond would affect the outcome there at all though... Maybe location or something?

Comment: One of those links is definitely an extremely active and current user... others not so much - but definitely still live users - probably a glitch in the matrix or something to do with the DB migration stuff...

Comment: @JonClements: as a moderator, we are sent to the *activity* page. Go to the *profile* tab, and it errors out. So the [*activity* page for Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4370109/brian-tompsett-%e6%b1%a4%e8%8e%b1%e6%81%a9?tab=topactivity) works just fine, but not so [the *profile* tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4370109/brian-tompsett-%e6%b1%a4%e8%8e%b1%e6%81%a9?tab=profile).

Comment: I wonder if this is another fallout from [Top bar notifications (global inbox, +reputation) reset after refreshing or visiting another page](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/327309)

Comment: Also triggered on the *Developer Story* tab, but not on the *mod dashboard* or *edit profile & settings* tabs.

Comment: These profiles are back up again now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We were cleaning up some old cruft related to work history that *could* be used to populate the Job Title shown below your username:

[image: Current Position, formerly in the profile editor]

This whole section was kinda redundant / unnecessary, and caused some amount of confusion:

- [How are all of these title/position fields correlated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377872/how-are-all-of-these-title-position-fields-correlated)
- [What is Just <3 code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317919/what-is-just-3-code)

As part of this, we've done a bit of refactoring for the logic that *uses* this data - specifically, a method that tries to format a title from some combination of the Role, Description and Organization fields that might have been populated from that form. This method originally lived in the Razor view that implements that part of the user page, and deftly avoided problems by using [this handy extension method named IsEmpty()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/gg548171(v%3Dvs.111)).

That method was moved to a normal CS file, at which point that extension method was no longer available by default. That *should* have broken the build (and would never have been committed), but it turns out we have a *different* extension method floating around our codebase...

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) => !collection.Any();
```

That's very different logic from what StringExtensions.IsEmpty() provides - critically, it doesn't cleanly handle a NULL parameter. But, since String implements IEnumerable, the compiler happily substituted the new extension method for the old and the build completed without complaint. All was well... Unless anyone ever happened to have a NULL value for one of the work history fields.

And they *were* null on those profiles.

The logic now checks for null explicitly, doesn't call *any* methods named `IsEmpty()`, and should therefore proceed cleanly as we continue stripping out this old logic. Hat-tip to Dean Ward for jumping in to fix it!

Comment: Do I understand this to suggest that you’re getting rid of “Just Less-Than-Three Code”? Also, excellent evidence for why extension methods are evil, especially when given generic names and using base types.

Comment: Yeah, that should be gone now @cody