# Change the title and company in my profile

Tags: support, profile-page

On StackOverflow, my profile shows a title and company name where I'm currently working at. I cannot find this information anywhere in my profile edit pages. Is it still possible to edit that information? It doesn't show up on other sites.

Update: Here's the part that I mean, highlighted with a yellow marker. I thought it would be obvious what a job title is.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What part of your profile shows the company/title part you are wanting to change?

Comment: they made some changes: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384245/8620333

Comment: @George_E I've added a screenshot.

Comment: @TemaniAfif So they had a rendering error. I didn't. How is that related?

Comment: @ygoe I have submitted an answer. I asked you to clarify because I didn't realise the title is only visible on the actual `Stack Overflow`.

Comment: Have you customized [your Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/143684) before? It might be taken from there.

Answer (score 5):

This is very easy to change.

1. Click on your profile in the top-right.
2. Select the `Edit profile and settings` section.
3. Edit where it says `Title`.
4. Scroll down to the bottom of the page to the two large blue buttons, and click your choice (I would recommend `Save and copy changes to all public communities`).

Use this image for reference (this is my profile for a demonstration):

[image: Editing profile title]

Comment: This field is empty in my profile edit page. So where did the text come from that is now visible in the profile?

Comment: @ygoe The title must have been written by you, whether you forgot or not. Either way, just follow the steps by changing the title and then make sure you `Save` it.

Comment: Yes, I must have written it. But why is is displayed but not in the edit form?! Is there a corrupted database?

Comment: @ygoe I'm not sure why. Do you mean that you don't get the box to edit, or it just says nothing in the box?

Comment: There are three input fields next to each other. Display name, Location and Title. The first two have the value that is publicly visible. The last one has a grey text "No title has been set" as placeholder but is otherwise empty. That's why I haven't considered this field to be relevant. I was looking for the field that shows the current value but can't find any. So that data must be stored somewhere but that data is currently inaccessible to me.

Comment: @ygoe Definitely sounds strange. Have you tried adding a word to test if it changes? If that works, then you can maybe change it to nothing or just a white-space if that does not work.

Comment: I guess I'll clear up the database inconsistency when I change that value. I don't have a problem with it, I was just wondering where I could set it. Seems like a bug in the software.