# Don't show old title when a user removes it from the profile

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, profile-page, privacy

I have a title in my Stack Overflow profile, which refers to my school and the class I was in when I registered 2 years ago.

However it's no longer relevant, so I was going to change it. But I couldn't find this information anywhere.

I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384588/change-the-title-and-company-in-my-profile) which refers to the same problem that I have.

I know that changing the title to anything else (currently it is '-') will change it, but if I leave a blank, even after changing it first to anything else, it's back to my first title.

So I would like to:

- Completely delete my title. Being able to have a blank, instead of a '-' or anything else.
- Know why my first title (and so my school name) is stored somewhere and why I can't edit/delete it

My story title isn't set. It's actually the same as my profile one ('-'). If I leave a blank in the profile title, the story one is also a blank, it's not my school name.

Others users tried

- One has a older title (not the first or the last) that show up when they leave blank the title field from the *Edit profile and settings*
- Two others have nothing when they leave a blank.

My title never changed during the last 2 years. So a possibility is that somehow during the last 2 years (or maybe before) a title was stored for some/all users. And this title is used when the user leave a blank in the title field.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. We should not save this infomration an unlimited time, and default back to it when the field is blank.

Comment: Also curious to why this info is stored.

Comment: When I try to remove my title, it shows a title which I've used before but it isn't my first title or my last title. No matter what I try, it always displays this specific title when I leave the box blank. Setting it to a zero-width space kind of hides it.

Comment: [No repro?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKEO9.png)

Comment: @TrebledJ after reading AlexanderZhang, I guess the title has been stored at a moment during the last 2 years. I never changed mine, so it show the first/only one. 
Maybe you didn't have a title at this moment.

Comment: What happens if you enter a non breaking space?

Comment: @Tschallacka It is ignored and the old title is shown as if I left the box empty. When I edit my title again it's not there. As I mentioned before a zero-width space doesn't get ignored though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. We used to have a "Career" section on the `Edit profile and settings` page, which we got rid of in April 2019. [image]

We were incorrectly falling back on this info if the `Title` field was `null`. We've fixed the bug and are currently in the process of dropping that obsolete table completely.

Answer (score 7):

The root bug should be addressed, but on an individual level, Stack Overflow also has a [GDPR Data Access Request form](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request) that you can use to submit a request to "Rectify or restrict [your] data".

> ### Rectify or restrict my data
>
> Update incorrect data or limit the processing of your data. Please use the ‘Request Details’ field to provide us with the specific changes you are looking to make.

You would like to correct/limit use of the obsolete title that they're storing, so this seems appropriate.

You appear to be a resident of the EU, so you might be able to legally enforce this request if necessary (presumably it won't be). Stack Overflow also allows non-EU citizens/residents to submit such requests:

> because we care about your privacy rights we make these access requests available to you whether you are in the EU or not.

Comment: So, I submitted a request to delete the obsolete data. I am waiting so see if it works, but I have a question about the process of accepting the question. The question evolved from me wanting to remove an old title (and you provided an answer) to some kind of bug reports affecting others users. Should I accept the answer because it solve my own problem, or should I wait for the problem to be fixed (if it has to be fixed, I'm a bit confuse by your first sentence)?

Comment: There's no rush to accept an answer, @JackRed, so you can wait as long as you like for one that is more helpful. Even if you do decide to accept, the bug report will remain "open" for the team to view and even possibly fix.

Comment: @JackRed It's up to you (accepts are a little ambiguous on meta), and what Cody said. Personally, I would not accept this answer; I'd leave the question unaccepted until there's a resolution to the root issue.