# Updating job in private Developer Story syncs to public SO profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, developer-story, privacy

A few months ago, I updated my Developer Story for procrastination, which included adding a new job role that I began last year.

My Developer Story is set to "private".

Today I noticed that my current company had been automatically copied into my [public] Stack Overflow profile's "Title" field.

Not cool!

Please abide by my privacy settings, or at least prompt/notify me when this sort of cross-syncing occurs.

Comment: This sounds [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385813/dont-show-old-title-when-a-user-removes-it-from-the-profile) but is [status-completed]. I guess regression.

Comment: Maybe you did edit the wrong thing as it needs a  whole answer to explain what options you have there: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377872/how-are-all-of-these-title-position-fields-correlated