# Job Title showed Employer Name without me adding it

Tags: bug, profile-page

I can't say *when* it was added, however, I noticed just now that my profile was updated so that my Job Title was "Database Administrator at {Employer Name}". I haven't made any changes to my profile recently (apart from just now to remove my employer's name) and I explicitly didn't want my employer displayed. You can see I'm specifically vague about who my employer is in my About Me section.

Why was my profile information altered without me doing so? I find this especially worse when the Job Title is public; effectively the information is PII as there are only *two* people at my company with said Job Title so if you contacted my company, you would most certainly be able to identify who I am. It is up to **me** if I share that information with the public; **not** Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's not particularly private. Your Developer Story is prominently linked from your profile, and this information is in your Developer Story.

Comment: Which is incomplete, @CodyGray, I never finished it; so why is that information viewable? My profile constraint "reminds" me *to* finish it. That, however, does not explain why my profile was changed without my permission.

Comment: It may be incomplete, but there's still *some* information that has been completed, and that information is displayed in your Developer Story. "Developer Story is a tab on your SO profile page, publicly visible to everyone. It links to your Developer Story, which contains your work history. Evidently, you have filled that in. I can see a title and a company name. These aren't being hidden to anyone who cares to look, aside from the issue of them being copied in one direction. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377872/how-are-all-of-these-title-position-fields-correlated

Comment: I feel that if actions in that menu affect *other* settings, @CodyGray, then that should be stated; after viewing said page you imply, there is nothing on it to state that my profile would be updated due to me thinking about completing said "story".

Comment: I think you're implying things that I am not saying. I certainly agree that there is no indication or expectation that making edits on the Developer Story would change fields on your main site profile. I was specifically addressing your claim that this is a security/PII breach. It cannot be, for the corresponding field on your Developer Story is also public, and publicly linked from your profile, so it is trivial to get this information. That makes it not a PII breach. It does still, however, violate UI/UX best practices, including the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: I think you're also implying something I am not saying,  @CodyGray , I didn't say there was a PII breach; I specifically didn't say this. If I felt it was breached, I would have been explicit on that. I said that the data is effectively PII, but I didn't say I felt my information was breached, just that it's up to *me* if i share that information [in the Job Title section of my Profile], *not* Stack Overflow's (poor choice of) UX/UI.